# ANOVA function when comparing logistic models has no p-value for Deviance

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, anova, model-fitting

I'm working with the biopsy dataset from the MASS library in R. I'm at the initial stages of creating a logistic regression model to see what variables have an impact in the probability of having a malignant tumor. I removed all rows with missing data (around 16 observations). All variables are significant on their own, so I started with the fullest model with all variables included and the third variable (V3 - Uniformity of cell size) was the least significant in this fullest model possible.

I created another model with V3 removed. I then wanted to use the anova() function to see if there is a significant difference in the fits of the two models. However, I get no p-value from my anova test. Does this mean the p-value is nearly is 1? Have I made an error somewhere in my model set up?

All input is appreciated!

```
#post removal of rows with missing data from biopsy in library(MASS)     
relevel(biopsy$class, ref = "malignant")
#assigns value of interst to malignant instead of benign. 
fullest.model = glm(biopsy$class~biopsy[,2]+biopsy[,3]+biopsy[,4]+biopsy[,5]+
                  biopsy[,6]+biopsy[,7]+biopsy[,8]+biopsy[,9]+biopsy[,10]
                ,family = binomial(link = "logit"))
model1 = glm(biopsy$class~biopsy[,2]+biopsy[,4]+biopsy[,5]+
           biopsy[,6]+biopsy[,7]+biopsy[,8]+biopsy[,9]+biopsy[,10]
         ,family = binomial(link = "logit"))
anova(model1, fullest.model)
```

Output I get:

```
      Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df   Deviance
1       674     102.89              
2       673     102.89  1 0.00090001
```

^See no pvalue!!

Comment: The deviance is a metric characterising the overall quality of your model fit. It has nothing to do with p-values. You can see the statistical significance (p-values, confidence intervals) of your *predictor variables* if you run `summary(model1)`.

Comment: The p-value is a test of the hypothesis that the reduced model fits the data just as well as the full model. The deviance in this case should follow a Chi-Squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom. The anova function should produce a p-value of the deviance following this distribution, but it does not for some odd reason in this case.

Comment: No, that is incorrect. In general, the p-value is the probability for observing data as extreme or more extreme, conditional on the null hypothesis being true, i.e. p-value = p(data|H_0). The deviance is a [goodness-of-fit statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)); it has no p-value. You are using an ANOVA type analysis to explore the validity of two GLMs, based on the deviance. This will *not* produce a p-value for the deviance (as you've correctly experienced).

Comment: If you want to perform a likelihood ratio test of your models (where the null model corresponds to the reduced model), you need to specify the correct hypothesis test; e.g. `anova(model1, fullest.model, test="Chisq")` will calculate the chi-squared-distributed likelihood ratio test statistic, and also the probability for observing a test statistic as extreme or more extreme (your p-value). This might be what you're after.

Comment: I've added an example below, please take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your input and example!

Comment: No problem @Omar123456789, glad to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. We generate some sample data, assuming the GLM `y = 0.5 * x1 + 4 * x2`.

   ```
   # Generate some sample data
   x1 <- 1:100;
   x2 <- gl(2, 50, 100);
   set.seed(2017);
   y <- 0.5 * x1 + 4 * as.numeric(x2) + rnorm(100);
   ```
2. We now fit two models:

   - `fit1` estimates coefficients for model `y = beta0 + beta1 * x1`,
   - `fit2` estimates coefficients for model `y = beta0 + beta1 * x1 + beta2 * x2`.

   ```
   # Fit two models
   fit1 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2);
   fit2 <- glm(y ~ x1);
   ```
3. Perform ANOVA analyses.

   ```
   # Default ANOVA (note this does not perform any hypothesis test)
   anova(fit1, fit2);
   #Analysis of Deviance Table
   #
   #Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
   #Model 2: y ~ x1
   #  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance
   #1        97     112.11
   #2        98     213.39 -1  -101.28

   # ANOVA with likelihood ratio test
   anova(fit1, fit2, test = "Chisq");
   #Analysis of Deviance Table
   #
   #Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
   #Model 2: y ~ x1
   #  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)
   #1        97     112.11
   #2        98     213.39 -1  -101.28 < 2.2e-16 ***
   #---
   #Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
   ```

   Note that the first ANOVA comparison does not perform any hypothesis test. It simply calculates the change in deviance between the two models. The second ANOVA analysis `anova(..., test = "Chisq")` performs a likelihood ratio test (it is the same as `anova(..., test = "LRT")`), by calculating the probability for observing a chi-squared distributed test statistic (i.e. the *change* in deviance) as extreme or more extreme. This latter quantity corresponds to the p-value of your hypothesis test.
4. Lastly, have a look at [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59879/logistic-regression-anova-chi-square-test-vs-significance-of-coefficients-ano). It provides more details on how to perform and interpret the output of an ANOVA analysis.